# Java plus equals or equals plus operator?

Tags: java

Is `+=` the same as `=+`?

I can't find any reason for why the plus sign is reversible.
For what reasons would I need to use one of the other? Where can i find docs on this i tried searching but didnt see the use of both.

Comment: [There is no such operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's not the same.

`x+=5` is equivalent to `x=x+5`.

`x=+5` (or `x=(+5)`) is equivalent to `x=5`.

Comment: Note that `x+=5` is only _mostly_ equivalent to `x=x+5`. The `+=` operation also casts, even lossily if necessary. For example, `int x = 3; x += 5.9;` compiles, whereas `int x = 3; x = x + 5.9;` does not.